# Script for concatenating delimited text files

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x

I need to concatenate a bunch of delimited text files. In the process, I need to add a new column to the data based on part of the name of one of the directories containing each file. The script works, but I have a feeling that it is inelegant in the extreme.

In particular, I'm wondering whether I should be reading the source files into a data structure that can later be written to file as a delimited text file. It seems like such an approach would be more general and easily extended.

In its current structure, I have doubts about the efficiency of how I'm skipping the header lines in source files with the is_header variable. It seems like this approach requires more condition-checking than should be strictly necessary. Can't I just iterate over some object? I tried `for row in reader[1:]:` but apparently objects of type csv.reader don't allow subscripting.

```
#! /usr/bin/env Python3

import glob
import csv

file_names = glob.glob('*/unknown/*.dat')

with open(file_names[0], 'r') as csv_input:
  reader = csv.reader(csv_input, delimiter = '\t')
  header = ['seed'] + next(reader)

with open('output.dat', 'a') as csv_output:
  writer = csv.writer(csv_output, delimiter = '\t')
  writer.writerow(header)

  for file_name in file_names:
    param_dir = file_name.split('/')[0]
    seed = param_dir.split('-')[0]

    with open(file_name, 'r') as csv_input:
      reader = csv.reader(csv_input, delimiter = '\t')
      is_header = True
      for row in reader:
        if not is_header:
          out_row = [seed] + row
          writer.writerow(out_row)
        is_header = False
```

Comment: Just do `next(reader)` to skip the header.

Answer (score 2):

There is some repetition between your header-reading routine and the rest of the code.  You could incorporate it into the main loop to remove that duplication and avoid opening the first file twice.  You already use `next(reader)` nicely to read the header; use the same technique to skip the header row.

To determine the seed from a file path, you look for a `-` in the file path.  Your glob should have a `-` to ensure that that succeeds.

```
import csv
from glob import glob

paths = glob('*-*/unknown/*.dat')

with open('output.dat', 'a') as csv_output:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_output, delimiter='\t')
    header_written = False

    for path in paths:
        param_dir = path.split('/')[0]
        seed = param_dir.split('-')[0]

        with open(path, 'r') as csv_input:
            reader = csv.reader(csv_input, delimiter='\t')

            header = next(reader)
            if not header_written:
                writer.writerow(['seed'] + header)
                header_written = True

            for row in reader:
                writer.writerow([seed] + row)
```